# How to highlight code in my blog with VS Code theme?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, jekyll-theme

I am trying to change the colour scheme of code highlighting in my Jekyll blog to the scheme in VS Code "light+" theme. I've tried searching the source code of VS Code and the themes in the Marketplace to find the corresponding .css file but ended up with failure.

I noticed that the same colour scheme (in "Light+") can also apply to my markdown preview, so I assume there's a convenient way. What should I do?

English is not my native language, and please excuse typing errors.

Comment: This could be useful: https://carbon.now.sh/

Comment: Look into Prism.js to execute syntax highligthing of your code when you generate your site (as opposed to running it on the client). As for using a specific VS Code theme, I'm not sure you'll find exact matches but Prism has a library of themes available.